# Как в html сделать линии по вертикали и горизонтали?

Tags: html

Как в html сделать линии по вертикали и горизонтали?

Comment: где, какие, для чего... сеанс телепатии?!)

Comment: Нарисовать и пустить фоном.

Comment: Вот к вопросу о том чтобы новички не могли писать пустые сообщения ЭТО ФАКТ и ЭТО НУЖНО ДЕЛАТЬ! Тут даже вопроса нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Линии</title>
<style>
#vertical{
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
left: 5px;
width: 1px;
height: 100%;
background-color: black;
}
#horizontal{
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
left: 6px;
width: 100%;
height: 1px;
background-color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="vertical"></div>
<div id="horizontal"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Напоминает анекдот про русских.  
Приказали в плену англичанину и русскому копать. Ну русский и выкопал яму 2 метра глубиной. Приходит надсмотрщик, англичанин говорит "а Вы нам не сказали зачем", тот и ответил "нам цветы сажать"...

Comment: как сделать 2 полски

Comment: @антон, ну для начала вам понадобится девушка)))

Comment: ... или бурундук.  
  
Или подумать.

Comment: тоесть 2 линии

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="border-top:1px solid #000">линия сверху текста</div>
<div style="border-left:1px solid #000">линия слева от текста</div>
<div style="border:1px solid #000">линия вокруг текста</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Линия по горизонтали - <hr>

Comment: такие вы все забавные)) или считаете что всё гениальное - просто?)

Comment: А ты везде будешь этот коммент копировать?)  Тебе никакие варианты ответа не нравятся.

Comment: они одинаковые, уникум :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label:before {
  content: "Для смены направления кликнуть в любом месте :)";
  color: red;
}

label, p {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#h:not(:checked) ~ p {
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1em 0;
  height: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}

#h:checked ~ p {
  border: solid;
  border-width: 0 1em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input id=h type=checkbox><label for=h></label><p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Ну или подойдите к решению нестандартно:

```
<hr style="size:400px; width:1px;" size="400px" color="#0000CC" width="1px">
```

Это очень просто, кроссбраузерно, но в то же время и работоспособно =)

Comment: такие вы все забавные)) или считаете что всё гениальное - просто?)

Comment: Просто надо уметь думать нестандартно....кодить по шаблону не получится.

Comment: ок... тогда вертикальную?)

Comment: 3 ошибки:

 - нет css-атрибута size
 - для hr нет html-атрибутов size, color и width
 - не закрыт тег

Вы бы хоть проверили что ли =/

Comment: Вообще-то есть =) Подучитесь чуток, почитайте мануалы....к тому же, это вы бы лучше проверили =) Я же не стал бы совать неработоспособный код, не проверив его предварительно. Я думал, что вы умнее, чтобы додуматься закрыть тег. Для hr есть аттрибуты и size и width(этот есть для всех DOM-элементов)....учитесь мыслить)

Comment: Поспорьте еще, лол))

Я ошибся в html-атрибутах, которые специально для hr определены, признаю.

Плз ссылку на документацию по css-size?

Comment: Для всех-всех объектов не определенны, признаю...в частности, для div`а точно, но "b" - это не объект! Это вообще атрибут текста =)
Про CSS:size, точно не знаю. В DreamWeaver`е он точно был =)

Comment: b - такой же объект, как div. его можно сделать блочным и он доступен через DOM-селекторы. Повторюсь, моя предъява не к подходу, а к качеству его использования. В предыдущем каменте валидный вариант. *Подсказка: для hr работает css-height.*